# When doing a git merge, what does the 'recursive' strategy mean?

Tags: git, merge, git-branch

I've seen this hundreds if not thousands of times, but what does it actually mean?

Are there other strategies that I can use, perhaps variants on mine or their?

What is the syntax for using different strategies and in what situations should I choose one over an other?

Comment: I've seen `octopus` a couple of times.

Comment: Are some of these questions addressed by the [git-merge(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) man page?

Comment: That has good and useful info but not really the same main question, I'm not primarily asking when I would use the different styles, my main question is what recursive means itself when I see it.  nit-pick perhaps but I think my question would be of use to others as is.